# How to set a property value based on a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization

The problem is I have this piece of code (Jquery UI):

```
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Remove": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

and now I have to internationalize it by giving to each button a word translation. I have the translation on the variables STR_REMOVE and STR_CANCEL, but if I do something like

```
        buttons: {
            STR_REMOVE: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            STR_CANCEL: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
```

the buttons (the properties) take the value "STR_REMOVE" and "STR_CANCEL", not its content. So, the question is, what can I do?

Comment: Well, I'm not quite familiar with jQuery UI, but try that: `buttons[STR_REMOVE] = function() {$(this).dialog("close");}` Might help.

Comment: Object properties may not be defined in a variable fashion with an object literal. J0HN's solution will help. BTW jQuery UI has nothing to do with this. This is a question about Javascript object definitions, and everything else should be removed from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
var STR_REMOVE = "my delete",  STR_CANCEL = "my cancel";

$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [{
        text: STR_REMOVE,
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }, 
    {
        text: STR_CANCEL,
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }]
});
```

have a look at the jquery ui doc: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-buttons

Comment: @naveen: sure, it's hard to type code in the SO answer field ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var buttons = {};
buttons[STR_REMOVE] = function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            };
buttons[STR_CANCEL] = function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            };
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
     resizable: false,
     modal: true,
     buttons: buttons
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this inline.  You'll have to declare the object first, then use the [square bracket member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) to set the properties:

```
var buttons = {};
buttons[STR_REMOVE] = function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
};
buttons[STR_CANCEL] = function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
};

$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: buttons
});
```

Comment: you can as a matter of fact do that. see fenders answer

Comment: @naveen Fair enough -- there is a jQuery UI solution. I've shown the only way to do what the OP wants with an object literal, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not tested:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Remove": function() {
            $(this).html(STR_REMOVE);
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel": function() {
            $(this).html(STR_REMOVE);
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```